# Site chat rooms listed as SE-network rooms

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

While in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468), click "leave", and the page you wind up on will be the "site" page (listing site-related chat rooms), but the site they're listed as being related to will be not JL&L but the SE network. Here's a screenshot: [image]

---

(By contrast, if you click the "chat" link atop any on-site page, the page you get to correctly indicates that it contains [image: "a list of rooms about Jewish Life and Learning"].)

Comment: Happens to me too!

Comment: Hm, this might depend on *how* you got into the chat room in the first place. Requires further testing.

Comment: This is normal behavior, and consistent across *all* sites on the network. I think it was originally made to encourage "favoriting" rooms, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce the issue in our current build of chat. If the problem remains, please let me know.